# Why API 22 insists on attaching to JDK 1.6?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to work with Java 1.7 in IntelliJ (Android Studio enough) and I believe I already have Java 1.7 selected, but somehow it insists that my Java version is 1.6 for (API 22). Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have the following in `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

I can use 1.7 features, but the dialog box keeps showing 1.6 which makes me feel very uneasy. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `File|Project Structure|SDK Location|JDK Location` points to the correct Java

Comment: Yes, it is pointing to the correct location. Screenshot added.

Comment: Which Android Studio do you have? I'm using 1.5 my 'Modules' dialog seems to look differently

Comment: I'm on IntelliJ 14. IntelliJ specifies which JDK an SDK is attached to. I think AS hides that information.

Comment: Dunno then, sorry. Been using AS as suggested